# Search sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, search

Sorry for my english. I try create dynamicly serch. Example: we input serch word `hellow`, i input `h`-> he is serch all word who name start in latter `he`-> he is serch all word who name start in latter `hel`-> he is serch... and so on. The word may be upper and lower case like this `HeLLow`. My example

```
   public List<Map<String, String>> getSearch(String tableName, String search) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE `name` LIKE " + search;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] names = cursor.getColumnNames();

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                    map.put(names[i], cursor.getString(i));
                }
                list.add(map);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

I try do like this:

`String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE name = " + search;`

`String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE name MATCH " + search;`

its not work too, i have always `list = 0`

Comment: so this has nothing to do with android or sqlite, but can be rephrased as `how does LIKE works in SQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build up the word on letter by letter basis, append it with the wildcard notation, i.e. `%`, for example, "he%", next letter "hel%"

Build up the `search` variable, for each iteration of letter added on or removed from, append it with the wildcard each time, like, 'Hel%', then combine the SQL like this

`String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE name LIKE " + search;`

The keyword is the SQL word `LIKE` which will get you the hit on the rows found that contains the word like Hel%.

Comment: thanks for answer, if i input `ow` its find my word( `hellow` )?

Comment: i create like this `String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE name LIKE " + "'"+ search +"%'";` its work nice. But if i have word like this `hellow-world` and i input `world` its not find my word(

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, consider using FTS (full text search) extension for SQLite. Querying with FTS works blazingly fast, provides results regardless of uppercase or lowercase and comes natively with SQLite for Android SDK.

You can find a working example below:
https://github.com/dawidgdanski/Bakery

Hope this helps somehow.